# ArgumentError in Articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this ArgumentError in Articles#show view after upload image to the page. Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #
Did you mean?  to_yaml

```
<% if @article.photo.present? %>
<%= image_tag(@article.photo, style:"width:100%") %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag 'banner.png', style:"width:100%" %>
<% end %>
```

Also here is my private method in Articles controller:

```
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :search, :music, :movie, :photo)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you using paperclip, this line is the problem for your error

```
<%= image_tag(@article.photo, style:"width:100%") %>
```

you can check the format setting in paperclip in your article model (app/models/article.rb)
usually it formed as thumbnail, medium, original, and you can write your code with sample below

```
<%= image_tag(@article.photo.url(:original), class: "thumb-style") %>
```

in your css file

```
.thumb-style {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I checked, and I have formed it as thumbnail http://prntscr.com/mmrk90  and after setting to my view this code <%= image_tag @article.photo.url(:thumb) style:"width:100%" %> I receive SyntaxError in ArticlesController#show (/home/viter/Blog/app/views/articles/show.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')' ...rticle.photo.url(:thumb) style:"width:100%" );@output_buffer... ... ^~~~~~)

Comment: another problem beside .url is style command, you can put in css for formatting size

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me))